How to create a wordlist with Crunch that starts with a fixed word and is followed by a combination of numbers and special characters
How do I use crunch to create a wordlist that starts with a fixed word and is followed by a combination of numbers and special characters? Min length = 8 and max length  = 10
Some examples
Helen123
Helen@12
Helen1234
Helen_567
Helen12345
Helen56789
Helen_1234
Helen123#4
Helen#678$

I already tried these. But it's only for digits OR special characters and with a fixed length.
crunch 8 8 -t Helen%%%
crunch 8 8 -t Helen^^^


The easiest way might be to specify the character set you want to use and use @ where required. What you want is for crunch to perform logical OR function on the 2 character sets, and that's not its strength. This is also possible with a simple python script.

When you supply a pattern with -t, you need to give crunch a minimum and a maximum length, each equal to the length of the pattern. To cover a range of lengths you need to run a sequence of crunch commands, each with its own pattern.
To get a combination of numbers and special characters, you need to give crunch a charset string. This can be done directly in the command line or from a file (with -f). The following commands use the former method:
crunch  8  8 '0123456789!@#$%^&*()-_+=~`[]{}|\:;"<>,.?/'\' -t Helen@@@
crunch  9  9 '0123456789!@#$%^&*()-_+=~`[]{}|\:;"<>,.?/'\' -t Helen@@@@
crunch 10 10 '0123456789!@#$%^&*()-_+=~`[]{}|\:;"<>,.?/'\' -t Helen@@@@@

Together they will generate the wordlist you want.
Alternatively use crunch to generate the variable substrings only; pipe the result to sed to add the fixed prefix (Helen) to each line. The advantage is you don't need -t now and thus you can cover the whole range of lengths with one crunch:
crunch 3 5 '0123456789!@#$%^&*()-_+=~`[]{}|\:;"<>,.?/'\' | sed 's/^/Helen/'


Many thanks. Crunch is much faster than exrex. Nevertheless exrex is also very useful to have in your toolbox.

You could use a tool that creates all possible regex matches, such as  exrex:
$ exrex 'Helen[0-9!-@[-`{-~]{3,5}'
Helen000
Helen001
Helen002
Helen003
Helen004
...
Helen~~~~`
Helen~~~~{
Helen~~~~|
Helen~~~~}
Helen~~~~~

